# Requiring IPv4 addressing for wi-fi connection in Bionic?

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

There's this coffee shop I visit occasionally whose Wi-Fi configuration does weird things to my Ubuntu laptop (a 2013 ThinkPad X1 Carbon running 18.04 LTS). Specifically, when the laptop connects to their network, it gets assigned an IPv6 address, but *not* an IPv4 address. So when I'm there, I can only access sites that have AAAA DNS records set up --- which many do not, even big/popular ones.

This has been a problem with some Wi-Fi networks for a long time, and not just for me either ([here's someone else who experienced it](https://willbradley.name/2017/05/15/fixing-ipv6-only-issues-in-ubuntu/)). In older versions of Ubuntu, though, there was a relatively simple workaround: you could go into the settings for a particular network connection and, in the IPv4 settings tab, there was a checkbox labeled "Require IPv4 addressing for this connection to complete". Checking that box solved the problem; if it was checked, the problematic network would hand out an IPv4 address along with the IPv6 one, and all would be well.

I updated my laptop to Bionic a couple of weeks ago, though, and was surprised when returning to the coffee shop after the update to find that the problem had returned. Then I was even *more* surprised to find that, in Bionic, the "require IPv4 addressing" checkbox was no longer there in the network connection settings. So now I'm back to being IPv6-only on networks configured like this one.

Is there a way in Bionic to set the "require IPv4 addressing" preference on a network connection the way you used to be able to do with the checkbox? Or, failing that, some global way to tell Ubuntu to hang in there for as long as it must to get an IPv4 address if one is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the `nm-connection-editor` program, you can enable this setting again.